# Two laravel projects in the same server. Conflict with Auth login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

When i am login with project1 and then i login to project2. My project1 will log out. How can i login the same time with two laravel projects?

i try to change `config/session.php` by change `path`

Project1- `config/session.php` default `'path' => '/',`

Project2- `config/session.php` i change to `'path' => '/pa',`

But i can't login with project 2
How can login with `Auth` with two laravel projects with the same server??

Comment: In `config/session.php` did you change the `'cookie' => 'this-here',` to be unique?

Comment: Also, are you using the same database for both projects?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are trying to use as localhost 
go to xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhost.conf
if you are using xampp
make virtual host like this

```
<VirtualHost project1.dev>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/"
  ServerName project1.dev

  CustomLog "C:/path/to/your/site/logs/project1.dev.access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "C:/path/to/your/site/logs/project1.dev.error.log"

  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

than
on more

```
<VirtualHost project1.dev>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project2/"
  ServerName project1.dev

  CustomLog "C:/path/to/your/site/logs/project2.dev.access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "C:/path/to/your/site/logs/project2.dev.error.log"

  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project2">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

now go to

```
C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

add this

```
127.0.0.1 project1.dev
127.0.0.1 project2.dev
```

now restart system and it should be fixed different domain different session

Comment: how can i access from Lan. When i type project1.dev from lan connection it's not working

Comment: its not require internet also so if its not working than you are missing something one question for you are you using xampp on your windows pc